# Filter IEnumerable<T> against IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have an object `Style` with a property `StockNumber`. I would like to filter a list of all `Db.Styles` against an `IEnumerable<string> stockNumbers` the user enters in a search. `DB.Styles` is an `IEnumerable<Style>`. Here is essentially what I am trying to do:

```
public IEnumerable<Style> LoadListOfStyles(IEnumerable<string> stockNumbers)
{
    return Db.Styles.Intersect(stockNumbers);
    // Need to filter Db.Styles based on stockNumbers
}
```

So is there an easy way to compare the list of all styles in `Db.Styles` against my search values in `stockNumbers` to return a filtered list of only the `Styles` the user has searched for? The only way I have seen to be able to do this is to have 2 IEnumerable objects to intersect, but loading the styles one by one from the stock numbers searched seems like a lot of unnecessary code. I am wondering if there is an easier way. Or do I need to roll my own method to filter the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return db.Styles.Where(style => stockNumbers.Any(sn => sn == style.StockNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was thinking of but I just didn't know the exact syntax. I'll accept this as answer as soon as the site allows.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<Style> LoadListOfStyles(List<string> stockNumbers)
{
    return db.Styles.Where(s => stockNumbers.Contains(s.StockNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `Where` clause.

```
public IEnumerable<Style> LoadListOfStyles(IEnumerable<string> stockNumbers)
{
    return Db.Styles.Where(style => !stockNumbers.Contains(style.StockNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `Intersect` as effectively a `Join` where the keys of each object are always "themselves".  Here you want to perform a join where the key isn't always "itself", so you use a `Join` (or, if you need to remove duplicates, a `GroupJoin`).

```
var query = from style in Db.Styles
    join number in stockNumbers
    on style.StockNumber equals number
    into numbers
    where numbers.Any()
    select style;
```